# Subgrid with floating method and padding

Tags: singularitygs

How do I get nested grid with Singularity? 
I've made a simple grid and need nested grids with floating method.

My sample: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7326030

Answer (score 1):

You should understand two things:

1. Singularity applies *relative* widths to columns.
2. All it does is generating CSS, completely unaware of your HTML structure.

So, if you apply a float span to a class, it will get `width: 33%`, for example. Every element with that class will have `width: 33%`, regardless of its nesting. This means that you can't create nested grids with a single level of non-semantic classes. You'll need two or more levels:

- `span1`, `span2`, `span3`...
- `grid1-span1`, `grid1-span2`, `grid1-span3` ... `grid2-span1`, `grid2-span2`, `grid2-span3`...

This results in bloated CSS. That's why the non-semantic approach should never be used when your environment allows you use the semantic approach (and Sass does lets you do that with little effort):

Structure:

```
#page
  #foo.container
    .subcontainer
      .column Foo
    .subcontainer
      .column Bar

  #bar.container
    .column Baz
    .column Quux
```

Styles:

```
$grids: 12
$gutters: 0.2

#foo
  .subcontainer
    +float-span(6)
    &:nth-child(2n)
      +float-span(6, last)
  .column
    +layout(6)
      +float-span(3)
      &:nth-child(2n)
        +float-span(3, last)

#bar
  .column
    +float-span(6)
    &:nth-child(2n)
      +float-span(6, last)
```

Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7360259

Also note two things:

- You don't need to span the first-level container, it's already 100% wide.
- You should be very careful with fixed margins in nested grids.